# How can i resolve tramp-error: Not a Tramp file name: using a /docker address?

Tags: python, debugging, tramp

Trying to set up `.dir-locals` to use a custom python interpreter inside a container so i can use `run-python` and get the REPL inside the container.

I have this setup which seems to partially work in that its trying to use the interpreter i have specified.

```
((nil . (
        (python-shell-interpreter . "/docker:hackdev_django_1:/usr/local/bin/python")
                )))
```

However I just get the below error.  I assume its something to do with the added slashes.

```
tramp-error: Not a Tramp file name: "/docker\:hackdev_django_1\:/usr/local/bin/python"
```

If I use `find-file` and navigate to the `bin` folder that works, and using the `which` command tells me that the path is correct inside the container. So I am at a bit of a loss.

```
GNU Emacs 25.2.2
Tramp version 2.2.13.25.2 built in
```

I tried upgrading but I could not convince Emacs to use my downloaded version over the built-in version.

Looking for next thing to try.  Is this perhaps a known bug ?

**Update 01**

The python shell calculate command runs the docker command through shell-quote-argument which is adding the slashes and breaking things.

I then have to add (setq tramp-histfile-override "/dev/null") to get around another issue where it looks for a history file which does not exist.

Currently running the code below to progress.

```
  (setq tramp-verbose 6)
  (defun python-shell-calculate-command ()
    "Calculate the string used to execute the inferior Python process."
    (format "%s %s"
            python-shell-interpreter
            python-shell-interpreter-args))
  (setq python-shell-interpreter "/docker:hackdev_django_1:/usr/local/bin/python")
  (setq tramp-histfile-override "/dev/null")
```

using C-x C-f I can type /docker:hackdev_django_1:/usrlocal/bin/py tab and have it list python.

[image: tramp buffer output]

Comment: Do you load `docker-tramp` in your init file?

Comment: I do indeed, and the fact I can open files uing /docker tells me that docker tramp itself is working. seems it something todo with run-python integration perhaps ?

Comment: Perhaps. Set `debug-on-error` to `t`, and show the backtrace.

Comment: I take you meant debug-on-entry this does nothing, most likely because its a handled error I assume ?

Comment: Actually you meant set the variable, same effect with that defined as true

Comment: I meant `setq debug-on-error t)` Hopefully, a Lisp backtrace happens if  the error occurs. If not, you might set `(setq tramp-verbose 6)` This shall produce a Tramp debug buffer, which might tell us more.

Comment: However, I believe this goes far further than stackexchange is intended for. Maybe you write to the Tramp mailing list, see the manual for details.

Comment: You may be right, Is there a way you can run a command direct from tramp ? I know you can connect to a shell like eshell and then run python but is that something you can call to run a command direct ?

Comment: After doing some testing I found that run-python is whats breaking the tramp url and adding the slashes, after this i get could not find binary error which is a bit strange so am hoping to find a direct run this command using this tramp url command in emacs.

Comment: As said already, with `(setq tramp-verbose 6)` you get a Tramp debug buffer which shows everything what Tramp does. If you change it to `10`, the debug buffer shall contain also Lisp backtraces for every error Tramp hits, even if this error is not propagated to user level.

Comment: made some progress based on your suggestions, will update with the latest info